# Military uprising and other problems in Tropico 5

Tags: tropico-5

I am playing Tropico 5 and I reach till Cold War stage easily. The problem begins here. After few months or years, I lose my military completely. Any one of these happens,

1) An military uprising starts and all defensive units turns against the country. Goes destroying everything. Loyal military units stand 1 against 3.

2) All military buildings go vacant. Even the foreign workers I invite run away in few months.

On my island, I see to it that there is sufficient food. Trade is good. All special citizens are bribed. Rebels are banished. The only problem is that suppply of power is insufficient.

Also I create more than one military building that is unlocked till that period with all ppssible upgrades. I put residentials, educational, religious and entertainment based buildings around militaty base for their well being.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: How much are you paying your soldiers; is it at least as much as other high school jobs? Do the militarist faction hate you? Do you have any edicts which reduce soldiers' job quality?

Comment: Actually, do you have a save file of a game shortly before or after the problems occur?

Comment: @Studoku I keep upkeep for all military buildings to highest. I suppose that is what you mean.

Comment: It is- I momentarily forgot that Tropico 5 used that system rather than actually setting wages.

Comment: Are your people happy? I usually focus on keeping my people happy more than anything else, and I almost never have any kind of problems with the military. I also barely even *have* a military.

Answer (score 1):

After playing over and over few times, I found few reasons to this problem.

1) I set recruitment standard for soldiers as High School grads. But I have inadequate amount of high schools on island to educate people. Thus, jobs remain open till I have enough high school grads.

2) Lack of liberty: I put 4 -5 of each military around each other on single section of island. Like creating a secured army area. This leads to lack of liberty and thus the uprising.

I need to understand how liberty works in Tropico 5 to see which buildings negate the effect of negative liberty around military buildings.